# Is it possible to build in future support for TLS 1.3 into a client using .NET TLS?

Tags: tls, .net

My (human) client has asked if a client service we are developing for them can somehow support TLS 1.3 for when TLS 1.3 officially rolls out. The issue is, the client service will be installed once, and probably never updated (I know this seems odd). It will be using the .NET implementation of TLS, so they want the service to somehow default to using 1.3 if and when the .NET framework on the client has it. Is this at all possible?

I have a feeling this is a big fat no, especially as the implementation of TLS 1.3 looks significantly different, i.e. with the new handshake, but my current knowledge in this domain is limited. Sorry if this is a really daft question, I have a feeling it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a more appropriate question for stackoverflow.

That said:

- It's impossible to know what MS will do. At one end of the spectrum, they could limit TLS 1.3 support to a specific release of .NET (in which case you'll be unable to support it without retargetting your application to that new version). At the other end, they might add support directly in schannel and indirectly to all libraries that relies on it and make it the negociated default in which case your application will support it automatically as long as it doesn't supply its own default (or force some other setting that makes it impossible to use TLS 1.3).
- It's also hard to give you an answer without knowing how you're using the .NET framework. If you're using only the highest-level interfaces and always using the default options then you're not going to have extra compatibility issue (although you'll be relying on the OS to be configured in a secure way).

Beyond that, I have a hard time understanding how you can reasonably expect the OS to be kept up to date but not your application. Or rather, if that is really a situation you are expecting then i would strongly suggest you invest in improving your auto-update system instead: that will solve way more issues than hoping for MS to add an implementation that is 100% compatible with your design without any change.

Comment: The implementation itself will never be in .NET. They'll put it into SChannel. But .NET will need an explicit opt-in because ServicePointManager only understands up to 1.2.

Comment: So the .NET 4.5 framework pretty much just provides an API to the SChannel SSP, through the SSPI?

Answer (score 0):

Since TLS 1.3 is not released yet and since it is not supported by .NET yet it will be impossible for the client for magically speak TLS 1.3 if the client never receives any software updates. But, it should be able to deal with a TLS 1.3 enabled server as long as the server also support the lower TLS version supported by .NET.